# Html.ActionLink Image button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3, ASPX pages.  I am trying to make an image button for ActionLink:
This one works well:

```
   <%: Html.ActionLink("New", "AccessCode", null, new { @class = "but_add" })%>
```

but this one did not work!!

```
  <%: Html.ActionLink("New", "Create", "CourseChapters", 
              new { courseId = ViewData["TestId"], @class = "but_add" }, "")%>
```

I have the class  in my style sheet

```
.but_add
{
    background-image: url('../../Content/images/b_add.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 85px;
    height: 27px;
    padding-left: 27px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your html attributes and routeValues as part of the same object. Should be:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people create an Ajax.ImageActionLink helper, but in some cases it's more appropriate to use an Html.ImageActionLink helper like the one here:

http://lottemae.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/html-imageactionlink-custom-helper-for-mvc/